# Convert 16bit Int to IP address in PHP

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I've been given the following PHP function and asked to write another function that reverses it.

```
function convertTo16bit($ipString) {
    $ipString = explode(".", $ipString);

    $ip = ($ipString[0] << 24) | ($ipString[1] << 16) | ($ipString[2] << 8) | ($ipString[3]);
    $lowNumber = $ip & 0xffff;
    $highNumber = ($ip >> 16) & 0xffff;
    return array($lowNumber , $highNumber );
}
```

First Question: I understand what the above code is doing but not why, can someone explain why you would need to create a lowNumber and highNumber for example?

Secondly, I need to write a function called "convertToIPAddress" which takes an array similar to the one outputted above and return a string in the form of an IP address. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Hm, maybe you could simply use `long2ip()` and `ip2long()` functions.

Comment: My initial thought when I saw this question were the two PHP functions... [`ip2long()`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) and [`long2ip()`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
function convert16BitIntsToIP($startingArray) {
    $low = $startingArray[0];
    $high  = $startingArray[1];

    $base = $high << 16 | $low;

    $ip1 = $base >> 24 & 0x00ff;
    $ip2 = $base >> 16 & 0x00ff;
    $ip3 = $base >> 8 & 0x00ff;
    $ip4 = $base & 0x00ff;

    $ip = "$ip1.$ip2.$ip3.$ip4";

   return $ip;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to write those functions yourself. You can use `ip2long()` and `long2ip()` for that purpose.

The reason for the upper and lower parts is that on a 32bit system (or even 64bit Windows) and integer is not large enough to hold all possible values. The PHP functions mentioned above "solve" that by returning negative numbers which has the same bits set.

> Because PHP's integer type is signed, and many IP addresses will result in negative integers on 32-bit architectures, you need to use the "%u" formatter of sprintf() or printf() to get the string representation of the unsigned IP address.
>   (Source: http://php.net/ip2long)

Comment: Yes, I could use ip2long and long2ip but the point of the exercise is to understand bitwise operations in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote this code:

```php
<?php

function convertTo16bit($ipString) {
    $ipString = explode(".", $ipString);

    $ip = ($ipString[0] << 24) | ($ipString[1] << 16) | ($ipString[2] << 8) | ($ipString[3]);
    $lowNumber = $ipString & 0xffff;
    $highNumber = ($ipString >> 16) & 0xffff;
    return array($lowNumber , $highNumber );
}

$ip = "192.168.1.17";

var_dump($ip);
var_dump(convertTo16bit($ip));

?>
```

And received:

```
string '192.168.1.17' (length=12)

array (size=2)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 0
```

I think this function is not correct. Don't use it.

Comment: I think that the line, starting with `$ip = ` should start with `$ipString = ` for this function to work.

Comment: What? Why? I can name variable as I want I think.

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko: `$ip =` inside of the function (the original code). A value is assigned to this variable inside the function, but it is not used. It just looks wrong. Or maybe the following two lines `$lowNumber =` and `$highNumber =` should use `$ip` instead of `$ipString`?

Comment: apologies, you're correct. I've changed the original function